# How to import category name in magmi in magento

Tags: magento, magmi

HI i am using magmi to import data below is my data structure

```
sku;name;attribute_set;categories
"100";"Product 1";"Default";"SHOP"
"101";"Product 2";"Default";"SHOP/About Us"
```

in this it is working fine but it is not importing category name. Please suggest where i am doing mistake .
thanks

Comment: did you select "On the fly category creator/importer"?

Comment: i dont have much experience in this please tell  about  fly category creator/importer"

Comment: You need to install extra plugins from http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/files/magmi-0.7/plugins/packages/ . after installing you will get "On the fly category creator/importer v0.2.3" option. check that. and it shloud work

Comment: Install magmi_extra_plugins_20130131.zip

Comment: You can find the more information here http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer

Comment: use category_ids column in your csv file 3 or 3,5

Comment: @ravipatel category_ids will work for only for integers rite?

Comment: yes i have integrated in my site. using magmi only cat id to possible category in import value. otherwise you can use stytem->import/export method to update ,add data there is possible on cat name.

Comment: You would only use the category IDs if you have previously created the categories. But even then you can still used named categories. You are doing the correct thing 'SHOP' and 'SHOP/About US'. Dushyant Joshi is correct; you should read the Magmi Wiki very carefully and practice using the on-the-fly-category-importer. It is an excellent plugin. [http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer)

Comment: I have tried in my local server and it worked,thanx a lot
But while configuring in live server,i m getting problem
i have given the correct path,but always its showing no csv file exist in var/import folder,
but already i have placed the csv file inside the folder

please help mee
thanx again

Comment: @RohitGoel, did you check for proper permissions of inside folders of "var"

Answer (score 0):

[Info for category import](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Import_categories)

```
_type;category_ids;name;sku;_attribute_set;status;visibility;enable_googlecheckout;tax_class_id;weight;


simple; 3,5;AIR FILTER RECHARGER SERVICE KIT;R2209;15.53;Default;1;4;1;0;0


-7,-12,27 // cat column exclude sku from catgories.
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Refer Below Url for Magmi Category Import
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Import_categories

Comment: need solution , not link .

Comment: It is solution only just check magmi, i will be just guiding you to right path